# Bash script conversion to fish

Tags: linux, bash, shell, fish

I'm trying to convert this script to fish:
https://github.com/masahide/OmniSSHAgent/blob/main/hack/ubuntu-bash.setup.sh

This is my progress so far:

```
set OMNISOCATCMD $HOME/omni-socat/omni-socat.exe
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$HOME/.ssh/agent.sock

function __get_omnisocat
  echo "Get omni-socat.exe"
  curl https://github.com/masahide/OmniSSHAgent/releases/latest/download/omni-socat.zip \
      -sLo omni-socat.zip
  unzip -o omni-socat.zip -d (dirname $OMNISOCATCMD)
  rm omni-socat.zip
end

function __get_socat
  echo "Install socat"
  sudo apt -y install socat
end


function setup_omnisocat
  [[ -f $OMNISOCATCMD ]]  || __get_omnisocat
  [[ -f /usr/bin/socat ]] || __get_socat
  
  ss -a | grep -q $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
  [[ $status -ne 0 ]]  || return

  rm -f $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
  
  (setsid socat UNIX-LISTEN:$SSH_AUTH_SOCK; fork EXEC:"$OMNISOCATCMD"; nofork &) >/dev/null 2>&1
end

setup_omnisocat
```

It should be fully converted except that main command substitution in the last function:

```
(setsid socat UNIX-LISTEN:$SSH_AUTH_SOCK; fork EXEC:"$OMNISOCATCMD"; nofork &) >/dev/null 2>&1
```

that raises this error:

```
omni-socat/ubuntu-fish.setup.fish (line 27): Command substitutions not allowed
  (setsid socat UNIX-LISTEN:$SSH_AUTH_SOCK; fork EXEC:"$OMNISOCATCMD"; nofork &) >/dev/null 2>&1
  ^
from sourcing file omni-socat/ubuntu-fish.setup.fish
.: Error while reading file 'omni-socat/ubuntu-fish.setup.fish'
```

And I don't understand how to convert it.
Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: bash `{ grouped cmds; }` is fish `begin; grouped cmds; end` and bash `(run in a subshell)` is `fish -c 'run in a subshell'`. Have you seen [Fish for bash users](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/fish_for_bash_users.html#)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the correct way to convert it (thanks to @masahide: https://github.com/masahide/OmniSSHAgent/issues/16#issuecomment-1107446991):

```
setsid nohup socat UNIX-LISTEN:$SSH_AUTH_SOCK,fork EXEC:"$HOME/omni-socat/omni-socat.exe" >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown
```